# A faster way to tell if a matrix is not non-singular.

Tags: matrices, determinant

If an n by n square matrix 'W' has at least one r by r sub-matrix that is singular and (n-1) > r > n/2  what 'conditions' are necessary so that W also singular?  Or is there no way to tell if given a matrix 'W' has at least one singular sub-matix if the matrix 'W' itself is singular without calculating it's determinant?

Comment: Why don't you try an nxn identity matrix and tell me what did you deduce.

Comment: Even if there are no zeroes at all, your conjecture is not true. Take a $4\times 4$ matrix with $2$'s on the diagonal and $1$'s everywhere else. This matrix is not singular but has singular $2\times 2$ submatrices.

Comment: Faster than what? There are roughly $n^2$ ways to choose two rows, and $n^2$ ways to choose 2 columns, so you have to check roughly $n^4$ $2\times2$ matrices. Whereas you can do row reduction in roughly $n^3$ operations; row reduction's much faster.

Comment: No. $\pmatrix{1&2&\pi\cr3&6&0\cr0&\sqrt2&0\cr}$ has the singular submatrix $\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&6\cr}$ but it's non-singular. But you are ignoring my earlier comment: even if your idea was correct, it would still be slower, not faster, than using row reduction.

Comment: 1. It is **not** our job to find correct versions of your fallacious statements; it is **your** job to put in enough thought to stop yourself from making fallacious statements in the first place. 2. You said the "shortcut" could make the analysis faster; I showed it was no shortcut at all. The appropriate thing to do in such a situation is to acknowledge the contribution that has been made to your understanding. 3. You refer to "the theorem", but there is no theorem until there is a proof, and you provide no proof. [to be continued]

Comment: 4. You speak of "changing" the matrix so the sub-matrix has a zero row or column, but you don't say what you mean by "changing". You are surely aware that the only way that a $2\times2$ matrix can be singular is for one row to be a multiple of the other, so it is not clear what there is left of your assertions.

Comment: OK: you can't exchange positions of columns or rows to make $\pmatrix{1&2&\sqrt2\cr3&6&\sqrt3\cr\sqrt5&\sqrt7&\sqrt11\cr}$ have a zero row or column, but it's non-singular, despite having a singular $2\times2$ submatrix.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: What about what J.W.Archibold wrote from Pitman Paperbacks on page 408 ; if an m+n by m+n matrix W has a n by n submatrix that is a zero matrix and n > m then W is singular.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ is non singular but has plenty of singular submatrices like $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @201044: are you suggesting it works for $n$ by $n$ matrices with $n>3$? Take the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix...

Comment: Casteels comment to your question provides other counter examples.